# Magento 2 : Getting error like "Only default scope allowed" when click to the theme option at the backend

Tags: magento2, admin, theme

Getting error like below :

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Only default scope allowed

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Only default scope allowed
#0 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Framework/App/Config/ScopePool.php(86): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Model\Config\Reader\DefaultReader->read(0)
#1 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Model/Config/Loader.php(94): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Framework\App\Config\ScopePool->getScope('default', 0)
#2 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Model/Config.php(450): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Model\Config\Loader->getConfigByPathForLoadForm('general_section', 'default', 0, '6', false)
#3 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Model/Config.php(331): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Model\Config->_getConfigForLoadForm(false)
#4 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Block/Adminhtml/Config/Form.php(158): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Model\Config->load()
#5 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Block/Adminhtml/Config/Form.php(171): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form->_initObjects()
#6 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Block/Adminhtml/Config/Form.php(475): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form->initForm()
#7 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(666): Codazon\ThemeOptions\Block\Adminhtml\Config\Form->_beforeToHtml()
#8 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(558): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#9 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(534): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('adminhtml\\confi...')
#10 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(206): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml\\confi...')
#11 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Layout.php(489): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('adminhtml\\confi...')
#12 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/generated/code/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/Interceptor.php(193): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('adminhtml\\confi...', true)
#13 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/AbstractBlock.php(507): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('adminhtml\\confi...', true)
#14 /home/krishsdn/public_html/rabitgo/app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/view/adminhtml/templates/system/config/edit.phtml(22): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->getChildHtml('form')
```

If anyone aware about this error please suggest me to solve this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is your admin user has access to all store resources?

Comment: Yes admin has full access of panel @magefms

Comment: are you using default theme?

Comment: what's in `app/code/Codazon/ThemeOptions/Framework/App/Config/ScopePool.php` around line 86 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same, or at least very similar issue, with a codazon theme. After some digging, I noticed my store id was incorrect in my URL string. It might have been a cache issue. When you look at your admin url when going to the theme options, check out this part... "general_section/theme_id/x/store/x/". In my case, the "theme_id" was showing "0" when it should have been "1".